# I used Google Analytics API v3 and v4 in same project. Will it create any issue?

Tags: java, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have working project which uses API v3. Now, i want to use new batch request for cohort which is provided in API v4 and i don't have time to migrate old code to API v4. So, will it create any issue if i use both API v3 and v4 in same project?

PS: its a JAVA project.

Comment: No idea really.   The data should technically be the same.   So if you request some data via v3 and some via v4 it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Analytics API V3 Java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/blogger/v3#add-library-to-your-project) and [Analytics Reporting API V4 client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analyticsreporting/v4) will work together. Each are within their own non-conflicting namespace.

This is necessarily true so that you can make [Management API V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) requests (to get the `viewId` for the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).